# Изменить стили css стороннего виджета iframe

Tags: css, iframe, виджет

Есть сторонний виджет, который представляет собой просто форму обратной связи iframe, вопрос: возможно ли изменить в нем какие-то стили на моем сайте? Если да, то как? !important не работает, к сожалению

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `iframe` - это непроницаемая граница между страницами. Внешняя страница никак не может повлиять на внутреннюю, а внутренняя - на внешнюю. Я в свое время пытался найти ответ на похожий вопрос, но так и не нашел ничего. Но если возможность есть, я бы тоже посмотрел на нее.

Comment: @Dmitriy  удручающе( но спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если `!important` не работает, то совершить подобное можно через `PHP` (метод `file_get_contents`). Тогда можно обращаться с `iFrame` как с простым текстовым файлом, а, значит, появится возможность редактировать `<head>` файла.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/351256)

Comment: @Dmitriy ту где-то ошибка. Мой ответ явно является ответом и ничем иным.

Comment: PHP, который у вас упомянут, - это язык программирования PHP? У автора вопроса язык программирования PHP не упомянут вообще никак. А если он ведет разработку на Java? Ваш ответ превращается в "переведите всю разработку с java на PHP, а потом...", что ответом не является.